# Adding CSS pseudo elements to reorder CSS elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using a mobile theme optimized from AMP, I need to add custom CSS to a theme to display a custom banner in a different position. For the purposes of this post, the banner is already in place using:

```
<div class="td-a-rec td-a-rec-id-header_mob "><div class="td-all-devices">
```

What I would like to do is place this below the elements with class:

```
<div class="td_module_mob_2 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack ">
```

But above the elements with class:

```
<div class="td-container td-pb-article-list td-main-content" role="main">
```

The ad needs rendering above the 'LATEST ARTICLES' block title, **WITHOUT** the ad being displayed in its current position. For a clearer picture of the amp version and CSS modification required see here [TBM](https://thebetmatrix.win/?amp).

I've tried a few custom CSS snippets using [freecodecamp.org/news/css-pseudo-elements-before-and-after-selectors-explained/](https://freecodecamp.org/news/css-pseudo-elements-before-and-after-selectors-explained/), but it doesn't appear to be working, since the ad is rendered dynamically using current entries in the theme panel will this be possible, as per the link above the following is currently being rendered:

```
<div class="td-a-rec td-a-rec-id-header_mob ">
  <div class="td-all-devices">
    <a href="https://inplayguru.com?r=31289" target="_blank">
      <amp-anim src="https://thebetmatrix.win/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/InPlayGuru-Design1-LM-320x100-1.gif" width="320" height="100" alt="InPlay Guru - Inplay Football Stats Scanner" class="amp-wp-enforced-sizes amp-wp-31d994b i-amphtml-layout-intrinsic i-amphtml-layout-size-defined" layout="intrinsic" data-amp-original-style="border:15px" i-amphtml-layout="intrinsic">
        <i-amphtml-sizer slot="i-amphtml-svc" class="i-amphtml-sizer">
          <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" class="i-amphtml-intrinsic-sizer" role="presentation" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgd2lkdGg9IjMyMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiLz4=">
        </i-amphtml-sizer><noscript>
        <img src="https://thebetmatrix.win/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/InPlayGuru-Design1-LM-320x100-1.gif.pagespeed.ce.WeGzAscmrw.gif" width="320" height="100" alt="InPlay Guru - Inplay Football Stats Scanner">
        </noscript>
      </amp-anim>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Pseudo elements selectors, requiring as detailed in the post, but expected template output isn't as desired and requires some additional CSS input to render the ad in the position detailed above.

Comment: _"For a clearer picture of the amp version and CSS modification required see here"_ - [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) - no; a proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ inside your question.

Comment: I've tried to tidy up the posted HTML so that it's somewhat readable, but while I can see the `</noscript>` closing tag, I can't see an opening tag in there; so it's quite possible you've got malformed HTML being returned or generated from somewhere. (Though it's entirely possible it's there, and I just can't see it for some reason.)